# In Wiremock how to write a mappingBuilder which matches a requestBody containing a json, having matchingJsonPath value equal to null?

Tags: java, wiremock

I want to write a java code which can produce following wiremock mapping-
"request":

```
{
                "urlPattern": "/kziwynya/ep1",
                "method": "POST",
                "bodyPatterns": [
                    {
                        "matchesJsonPath": {
                            "expression": "cursor",
                            "equalTo": null
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
```

If we write matchingJsonPath("cursor, equalTo(null)), it gives nullPointerException inside equalTo method.

Answer (score 0):

The `absent` matcher is what you need here:

```json
"bodyPatterns": [
  {
    "matchesJsonPath": {
      "expression": "cursor",
      "absent": true
    }
  }
]
```